# Inheritance a Point

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, point, shapes

Hello all I'm new in  C# programming. I'm learning inheritance, and I have a question. I want to inheritance a point with x,y coordinates and then inheritance Point M:Point with measure variable m so (x,y,m). I have to use constructor with parameters. I will show you a example of my work till now. The problem is How can I use a constructor that this should be true? Thank you!
http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf - From here you can see the subject Point->PointM->PointZ.

```
class Point
{      
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}

class Point M : Point
{
    public double M { set; get; }  
}

class Point Z : Point M
{
    public double Z { set; get; }        
}
```

Comment: See [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Some C# specific adivce here is to remember the difference between reference type (class) and value type (struct). A point would probably be a struct, since just like numbers and other "values", any two points with the same coordinates are indistinguishable. Second: it is often useful to use "composition over inheritance", that is, when you want a point with M, make a type that *contains* both a point and measurement, rather than extending the point with a measurement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the standard way for writing constructors.
The base class `Point` defines its own constructor, and classes that extend `Point` should call its constructor with the `base` keyword.

```
    class Point
    {      
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }

        public Point(double x, double y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
    class PointM : Point
    {
        public double M { set; get; }  

        public PointM(double x, double y, double m) : base(x,y)
        {
            M = m;
        }
    }
```